# How to limit connection count when running many Copy operations concurrently?

Tags: azure, go, tcp, azure-storage

I have code which runs 200 goroutines concurrently. Each goroutine issues [`Copy`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage#Blob.Copy) operations in serial. Each `Copy` makes two requests:

1. [`StartCopy`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/storage/copyblob.go#L72) (PUT request)
2. [`WaitForCopy`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/storage/copyblob.go#L77) (HEAD request)

After each http request, [`readAndCloseBody`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/master/storage/copyblob.go#L113) is called, which is important for ensuring connections are reused. Additionally, I've set the transport to http.DefaultTransport and set `MaxIdleConnsPerHost` and `MaxIdleConns` to 200, which is important since it defaults to `DefaultMaxConnsPerHost` == 2.

Despite all this, when I run `lsof`, I frequently see many **more than 200** TCP (ESTABLISHED) entries - sometimes up to 1000. Here's an example:

```
main 24217 jsmith 377u IPv4 0x364ecf4bed03d3d 0t0 TCP :50248->51.4.208.24:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

Any idea where connections might be leaking/how to limit connection count?

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage"
)

func main() {
    // create and initialize a client
    client, _ := storage.NewBasicClient(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_KEY)

    // use DefaultTransport with configs that limit conns
    client.HTTPClient.Transport = http.DefaultTransport
    transp, _ := client.HTTPClient.Transport.(*http.Transport)
    client.HTTPClient.Transport = http.DefaultTransport
    transp.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 200
    transp.MaxIdleConns = 200

    rootClient := client.GetBlobService().GetContainerReference("foo")
    numRoutines := 200
    numRequestsPerRoutine := 100

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for j := 0; j < numRequestsPerRoutine; j++ {
                sourceBlob := rootClient.GetBlobReference("fileA")
                destBlob := rootClient.GetBlobReference("dirX/fileA")
                destBlob.Copy(sourceBlob.GetURL(), nil)
                time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I'm running go1.10 on OSX 10.3.2 and using `github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage` at [`56332fe`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/commit/56332fec5b308fbb6615fa1af6117394cdba186d).

Comment: It would be helpful if you would create a full example that compiles and can be run ([mcve]). Your current example won't compile and is calling a lot of code that isn't in your question. We can't say anything meaningful about code we don't see ;-)

Comment: I've made a bunch of changes to the code - now all someone really needs is a free, basic azure account to run the code. (There are many API questions on SO which require some kind of account to recreate so this seems fine.) If you have other complaints that I could fix to get you to remove your `-1`, please let me know!

Comment: Are you sure the code compiles, and that it demonstrates the problem you're having? Did you test it? Because I don't see `env` being defined anywhere, `err` being assigned and not used, etc.

Comment: ok. i fixed it. only thing user needs to enter is account credentials.

Comment: Add your lsof command and some output too. Are most of these connections in TIME_WAIT state? That would be perfectly normal.

Comment: Updated with an example entry

Comment: Are you using "keep-alive"?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http search `var DefaultTransport RoundTripper`, you can see that it does not set `DisableKeepAlives` so DisableKeepAlives is false so "keep-alive" should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [connection leak in the azure library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/pull/1539/commits/475dde0c61b55d1619215fe28c3aba375690162b). The fix has been merged into `dev` and will probably be included in the next release.